# Magic method for python del statement?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Quick question, what is the magic method python calls when you say `del object`? I know it's not `__del__` and it isn't `__delete__`, so what gets called if anything? If nothing is called, then how can I customize the events that occur when you delete an object?

---

Take a look at the following example:

```
class SingletonError(Exception):
    pass

class Singleton(type):

    def __new__(metacls, name, parents, kwargs):
        cls = super(Singleton, metacls).__new__(metacls, name, parents, kwargs)
        cls._instance = None
        return cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            inst = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            inst.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instance = inst
            return cls._instance
        else:
            raise SingletonError("Cannot initialize multiple singletons.")

class Logger(object, metaclass = Singleton):

    def __new__(cls, *logging_args, **logging_kwargs):
        self = super(Logger, cls).__new__(cls)
        logging_args_dict = {'log%i' % pos : i for pos, i in enumerate(logging_args, 1)}
        kwargs = dict(logging_args_dict, **logging_kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = kwargs
        return self

log = Logger()
```

When I delete log I would like it to set Logger._instance to None again, so you can reinitialize the singleton. How might I do this?

Comment: You can't, because `del` doesn't delete the object, it deletes the *name* that points to the object.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__

Comment: Okay, I edited the question to include the scenario I am faced with and why I brought up this question in the first place.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you do `log = Logger()` and then `foo = log` and then `del log`?  The Logger object still exists under the name `foo`.  The object can't know how many names are referencing it.  You're better off giving your class a method called `clear` or `delete` or something that explicitly resets `_instance`.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes a lot more sense, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [weak reference](http://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) instead; as all references to the `Logger()` instances are cleaned up, the weak reference won't prevent the object from being reaped.

```
import gc
import weakref

def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    gc.collect()  # optional, clear existing weak references
    inst = cls._instance and cls._instance()  # de-reference the weakref
    if inst is None:
        inst = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        inst.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls._instance = weakref.ref(inst)
        return inst
    else:
        del inst  # clear local early
        raise SingletonError("Cannot initialize multiple singletons.")
```

`cls._instance` is now a weak reference object; you call it to retrieve the referenced object, and if it returns `None` the object is gone and you'll need to create a new one.

Just take into account that the deletion is not necessarily going to be instantaneous; garbage collection needs to run to reap the object once the last regular reference has been removed.

The [`gc.collect()` call](http://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) as the first line in the `__call__` ensures that any weak refences are cleaned up before testing.